# How to create a simple screen scraper in PHP

Tags: php, screen-scraping

I am trying to create a simple screen scraper that gets me the price of a specific item. Here is an example of a product I want to get the price from:

> https://www.flanco.ro/telefon-mobil-apple-iphone-14-5g-128gb-purple.html

This is the portion of the html code I am interested in:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRwcH.png)

I want to get the '4699' thing.

Here is what I have been trying to do but it does not seem to work:

```
$html = file_get_contents("https://www.flanco.ro/telefon-mobil-apple-iphone-14-5g-128gb-purple.html");
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
//Now query the document:
foreach ($xpath->query('/<span class="price">[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+/i') as $node) {
    echo $node, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Have you checked whether the `$html` variable does actually contain the price? I know it does when you use the browser, but that doesn't mean you get the same result in PHP.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes, it does contain the price. When I echo $html I get the exact same page except the css obviously

Comment: Turn on error reporting, it does not like the page and gives errors as part of the `$doc->loadHtml($html);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use standard PHP string functions to get the price out of the `$html`:

```
$url   = "https://www.flanco.ro/telefon-mobil-apple-iphone-14-5g-128gb-purple.html";
$html  = file_get_contents($url);
$seek  = '<span class="special-price"><span class="price">';
$end   = strpos($html, $seek) + strlen($seek);
$price = substr($html, $end, strpos($html, ',', $end) - $end);
```

Or something similar. This is all the code you need. This code returns:

```
4.699
```

My point is: In this particular case you don't need to parse the DOM and use a regular expression to get that single price.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are a few price classes on the page. I would specifically target the pricesPrp class.

Also on your foreach you are trying to convert a DOMElement object into a string which wouldn't work

Update your xpath query as such :

```
$query = $xpath->query('//div[@class="pricesPrp"]//span[@class="special-price"]//span[@class="price"]');
```

If you want to see the different nodes:

```
echo '<pre>';
foreach ($query as $node) {
    var_dump($node);
}
```

And if you want to get that specific price :

```
$price = $query->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $price;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$html = file_get_contents('PASTE_URL');

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"));    
@$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

$result = $selector->query('//span[@class="price"]');
foreach($result as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```